# Does the connect(2) call make use of a full struct sockaddr_in or could it just suffice with a struct in_addr?

Tags: c, network-programming

I'm curious because the man page of connect(2) is pretty short and it takes a struct sockaddr* which is normally cast anyways..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sockaddr_in` and `in_addr` aren't even similar. There's no way that would work. There different because more than an address is usually needed. For example, a port number is needed to establish connect a IP socket.

Answer (score 1):

How the `connect(2)` call works depends on the socket domain you're using (i.e. the value passed as the first parameter to [`socket(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket)).  If you're using the `AF_INET` protocol family, then `connect` expects a `sockaddr_in`.  If you're using the `AF_INET6` protocol, then it expects a `sockaddr_in6`,  Other protocol families have their own address structure.

Whichever protocol family you're using, you should only use that family's address structure, cast to a `struct sockaddr`, when calling `connect` or any other socket functions.